# Why is my dateTimePicker entering a null date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a Win Forms application with a DateTimePicker defined like this:

```
Private new_reminder_date As DateTimePicker
```

Later on the form I enter the date into a mysql database like this:

```
 query = "insert into reminder (rm_userid,rm_date) values (" & _
                    "'" & logged_in_user & "'," & _
                    "'" & new_reminder_date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")')"
```

Most of the time, this works and the date gets entered correctly. But sometimes it gets entered as 0001-01-01 00:00:00. From what I have found, this happens when you try to enter a null value into the date field when null values are allowed (yes, the field does allow null values). I just can't figure out why it only happens sometimes and why is my DateTimePicker giving a null value sometimes?

By the way, I don't care about the time value. The field was originally set up as a dateTime field and i can't change it now, so I just leave the time as 00:00:00.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking what your `new_reminder_date.Value.ToString(...)` is returning, as well as what the raw value is?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine on all of my checks, but it only happens about one out of a 100+ times. I can't catch it.

Comment: Where do you run this code? (In which form event)

Comment: What do you mean by raw value? I copy the query to the clipboard right before it gets sent to the database so I can seen what is being sent and I've used a messagebox to show me the value before sending it. I've stepped through it with the debugger and it always looks correct.

Comment: I use a button (Submit) and I have an event that catches the button click.

Comment: According to documentation: _If the Value property has not been changed in code or by the user, it is set to the current date and time (DateTime.Now)._ So I would try to search if you change that value somewhere

Comment: well, if it happens intermittently, then you should log all of the queries and wait for one to blow up. maybe it's not php/mysql at fault, and you're getting (or passing around) bad date strings  at the VB level.

Comment: why are you converting a perfectly good DateTime *value* to a string?

Comment: unless I convert the format, VB.Net tries to send it as "2/9/2015 4:05:09 PM" which MySQL doesn't accept. So I have to reformat it to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: I don't suspect MySQL at all. I really think it is at the VB level, I just can't find where it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you are missing something here. the &" symbol.

```
query = "insert into reminder (rm_userid,rm_date) values (" & _
                "'" & logged_in_user & "'," & _
                "'" & new_reminder_date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"
```

Comment: You are correct. I lost it in the copy over to SO. But the syntax correction doesn't solve the problem.